# single spacing won't work in gb4e translation lines

Tags: line-spacing, linguistics, gb4e

I have a document that must be in at least 1.5 spacing in the body text. I am using the `gb4e` package to gloss a few hundred linguistic examples. Sometimes, the translation of these examples end up being multilined. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\title{test}
\date{December 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\doublespacing
\section{Introduction}
        \begin{exe}
        \ex
        \begin{footnotesize}
        \gll  jekk asdas mniuuya mluy kju ddwqe, \textbf{sh-z-vuu} juuil kju ssa-mqwcx-e \\
              {there} {both} {never.\textsc{1pl.3sg}} {we} Kew Dwek, \textsc{fut}-jump-\textsc{1.pl} again Kew \textsc{fut}-sleep-\textsc{3.sg}.\\
              
        \trans\singlespacing `And there it is: we never will overtake Kew Dwek until he sleeps once more' (uttered sarcastically)
        \label{ive1}
        \end{footnotesize}
        \end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE for spacing issue]

I would like to make the translation line single spaced, but as you will notice the `\singlespacing` command does not work. I am using Overleaf to edit the document, so I am not sure how to edit the `gb4e` settings directly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `\par` ("paragraph break") instruction between `(uttered sarcastically)` and `\label{ive1}`. Or, just insert an all-blank line after the `\label` instruction to create an implicit paragraph break.

Incidentally, `\footnotesize` is a switch. To limit its scope, issue `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\title{test}
\author{}
\date{December 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\doublespacing

\section{Introduction}

\begin{exe}
\ex
\begingroup
\footnotesize
        \gll  jekk asdas mniuuya mluy kju ddwqe, \textbf{sh-z-vuu} juuil kju ssa-mqwcx-e \\
              {there} {both} {never.\textsc{1pl.3sg}} {we} Kew Dwek, \textsc{fut}-jump-\textsc{1.pl} again Kew \textsc{fut}-sleep-\textsc{3.sg}.\\
              
        \trans\singlespacing `And there it is: we never will overtake Kew Dwek until he sleeps once more' (uttered sarcastically)\par % <-- "\par" is new
\label{ive1}
\endgroup

\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had actually already used footnotesize and some items were still multi-line, but the \par works perfectly, thanks you!